# Internet over Airport Express issue

Tags: wifi, airport, internet

I recently switched ISP from an internet over phone line based solution to fiber broadband. While the increased speed is great, there is an issue with my Airport Express(es). The setup is as following:

The first Airport is connected straight to the ethernet socket wall outlet.
The second Airport is connected by pairing to the first Airport.

When my Macbook Air (13", 2012) comes back from sleep the computer connects to the Airport just fine, but does not manage to connect to the internet. See the below screenshot of Airport Utility. Clicking the Internet button it just says that internet is disconnected.
[image: Airport utility, mac]

Meanwhile, my iPhone for instance, is still connecting just fine, see screenshot below:
[image]

Disconnecting the ethernet cable from the Airport and simply reattaching it again brings back internet connectivity across all devices.

Its the same phenomenon if doing the opposite, e.g. restarting the iPhone also leaves it connected to the Airport but not the internet when its back up.

## - Update -

Based on @StuartH's advice, I enabled "Router mode: DHCP and NAT" (Edit settings for Airport connected to ethernet -> Network)

New devices now seem to get an IP address. The Airport utility displays lots of problems, even though both internet services and Airplay streaming to this Airport works.
[image]

Comment: When this happens again, check to see that your device that says there is no internet connectivity has an IP.  Might be that it's having trouble renewing the DHCP lease

Comment: @StuartH Yes you are right. When the machine connects to the Airport it does not receive a new IP number. Pressing the "Renew DHCP lease" does not help. Disconnecting and connecting the ethernet cable gives the computer an IP straight away.

Comment: I have no idea how the fibre connection works, but it sounds like the fibre is handing out IPs. Have you tried enabling NAT on the Airport attached to the wall outlet and let that hand out IPs on a local subnet?

Comment: @StuartH See above edit.